# Why does containsObject not work on an NSSet copy of NSMutableSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsset, nsmutableset

I’m having an issue when creating a set copy of a mutable set, and then having containsObject fail for the (new) set copy.
For example:

`NSString *sameID = @"XYZ";`

Then on main thread/sometimes on different thread:

```
[mutableSet addObject:sameID];
NSLog(@"adding Object: %@", sameID);
```

Then on a background thread, always after (I've verified with logging that) sameID has been added:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSSet<NSString *> *newSet = self.mutableSet.copy;
    if ([newSet containsObject:sameID]) {
      // do stuff
    }
});
```

Seen with a breakpoint:

```
1. po [newSet containsObject:sameID] // returns NO
2. po [self.mutableSet containsObject:sameID] // returns YES
```

I've tested that there is no additional or hidden whitespace for the sameID string. AFAIK containsObject for sets containing NSString uses isEqual which doesn’t/shouldn't matter if the strings have different pointers, right?

Edit: Some additional information: the NSStrings that are being added to the mutableSet are happening on different threads but always before creating the newSet copy. Creating and checking newSet is being done on a background thread which is why I'm copying mutableSet (and I'm seeing with logging that this is always after having added string(s) to mutableSet). So I see with log statements that the string (sameID) was added to mutableSet, then on a background thread I'm copying mutableSet to be a set and quickly checking that set for the same string (sameID) and it's not there.

Edit2:
I've tested the code below and it passes for me, however when I tried implementing the same solution regarding above it still has the same result (mutableSet contains the string yet newSet does not).

```
import XCTest
import Foundation

class CustomObj: NSObject {
    let id: String

    init(id: String) { self.id = id }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let other = object as? CustomObj {
            return self.id == other.id
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        return id.hashValue
    }
}

func testSetStrings() {
    let set = NSMutableSet(object: CustomObj(id: "String-1"))
    let copySet: Set<CustomObj> = set.copy() as! Set<CustomObj>

    let customObjForTest = CustomObj(id: "String-1")

    XCTAssertTrue(set.contains(customObjForTest), "Does Not Contain")
    XCTAssertTrue(copySet.contains(customObjForTest), "Copy Does Not Contain")
}

testSetStrings()
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? Quick testing, and I cannot reproduce your result...

Comment: Hey @DonMag thanks for replying I've updated my comment with some more info

Comment: Hmmm... tried your code in a unit test sample, and both Asserts passed. Also tried it in a simple single-view app, and both return true: https://pastebin.com/S6ukHpAH

Comment: Since your edit notes that the test code works, I think to help you resolve this, you'll need to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your replies and the link @DonMag I've updated my comment further please let me know if you think it needs more info.

Comment: You're performing the copy on the background thread. That means there's a race condition if you modify the original on the main queue before the background dispatch executes. Typically you would copy the set *before* dispatching it to another queue so that only one queue is allowed to access the set.

Comment: I'm particularly concerned with "on main thread/sometimes on different thread." A given NSMutable set should be accessed on exactly one queue. "Sometimes" feels like a red flag, unless you have been very careful in code you haven't shown us. I suggest turning on the thread sanitizer as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier I'm looking into the thread sanitizer as well as trying your advice for one queue being allowed to access the set, I'll report back.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks again for your feedback, by using thread sanitizer I was able to figure out I had a data race when I was accessing (copying) the NSMutableSet on one thread and at the same time (potentially) writing to the same set on another (different) thread. So I implemented a serial queue for ensuring all work related to the NSMutableSet in question is done on the same thread and the issue appears to be resolved. [This video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/412/) also helped me as well for anyone else out there.